# Как изменить имя файла при отправке на e-mail?

Tags: php

Для отправки письма с вложением использую такую функцию:

```
function sendMailAttachment($mailTo, $from, $subject, $text, $file = false) {
        $separator = "---";
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from\nReply-To: $from\n";
        if($file) {
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$separator\"";
            $bodyMail = "--$separator\n";
            $bodyMail .= "Content-type: text/html; charset='utf-8'\n";
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable";
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
            $bodyMail .= $text."\n";
            $bodyMail .= "--$separator\n";
            $fileRead = fopen($file, "r");
            $contentFile = fread($fileRead, filesize($file));
            fclose($fileRead);
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n"; 
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
            $bodyMail .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename==?utf-8?B?".base64_encode(basename($file))."?=\n\n";
            $bodyMail .= chunk_split(base64_encode($contentFile))."\n";
            $bodyMail .= "--".$separator ."--\n";
        }
        else {
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
            $bodyMail = $text;
        }
        $result = mail($mailTo, $subject, $bodyMail, $headers);
        return $result;
    }
```

Дело в том, что имя файла генерируется случайным образом (рандомное число). Переменная `$file` содержит полный путь к файлу. В письме приходит файл с именем, например `3211955146559`. Как изменить имя файла на, например, `attachment`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.rename.php не?